# golangci-lint, отключение линтеров

Tags: golang

Использую golangci-lint встроенный в VSC, хочу отключить линтер errcheck
в .golangci.yml добавил нужный линтер в

```
    linters:
      enable-all: true
      disable:
        - maligned
        - prealloc
        - gochecknoglobals
        **- errcheck**
```

и все равно он срабатывает.

Единственное может я не в тот конфигурационный файл добавил, я добавил в файл который располагается тут:
D:\GoMy\src\github.com\golangci\golangci-lint

D:\GoMy - добавлен в GOPATH

Answer (score 0):

Конфигурацию `golangci-lint` нужно в каталог с проектом поместить.